# I need transform array to json

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a array of objects like this in php:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [text] => aa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [text] => valladolid
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [text] => valencia
        )

)
```

I use json_encode to convert array in php to javascript

```
var data = '{{listCountries|json_encode|raw}}';
```

And this, they transform in:

```
var data = '[{"id":1,"text":"aa"},{"id":2,"text":"valladolid"},{"id":3,"text":"valencia"}]';
```

And i need, without single-quotes:

```
var data = [{"id":1,"text":"aa"},{"id":2,"text":"valladolid"},{"id":3,"text":"valencia"}];
```

Comment: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @Andreas is right. I'm posting a small code snippet to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.parse('{{listCountries|json_encode|raw}}')
```

EDIT: paste that into your php template and you should be good to go! Credit goes to @Andreas for finding it first.

Comment: Thanks to @Andreas and javierprovecho for answring first!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript will receive your perfectly encoded JSON in String format, You have to **DECODE/PARSE** it

```
JSON.parse(YOUR_STRING); // native JavaScript JSON parser, supported in major wab browsers
jQuery.parseJSON();      // for JQuery
```

...

Comment: I don´t use jquery but a lot of thanks for the help! ;-)